# Convert Attachment to ByteArray in java

Tags: java, attachment

How to convert Attachment to ByteArray in java?

I have created an Attachment object in java and attached a PDF to it.
Here is the code

```
ByteArrayInputStream pdfStream = null;
pdfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
AttachmentImpl pdfAttachment = new AttachmentImpl("application/pdf",pdfStream);
```

Can some one tell me how to retrieve back the bytearry from the attachment ?

Comment: `AttachmentImpl` knows how to convert the bytes to the object. So you'll have to look into that to know how to convert the object back into bytes. Can we see the code for `AttachmentImpl`?

Comment: I am not supposed to share it. But this class does not have any implementation to convert it into bytestream.

Comment: How does it convert to object? It might be using some other libraries or API to create the object.

Comment: Is this not possible in java??

Comment: Of course it is. Conversion of an object to bytes is called serialization, and the reverse process is deserialization. I can write a serializer that represents the 1 as byte array [0,0,0,1] or [1,0,0,0] or anything else. But then, when I am trying to get back the number 1 (deserialization), I'll have to use the same logic, right? That logic is hidden by the `AttachmentImpl` class. Only by knowing that can you get back the object.

Comment: Thank you Raze2dust. Its working for me. Actually i missed to read the file that is converted as attachment. Thanks for your help